# Shows only the last marker info window even though there are 154 others

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, google-maps-api-3

So I managed to get markers and info windows workin using razor and google maps api doing the following:

```
@{
            IEnumerable<UFA.Location.Core.Location> Location = UFALocation___Front.Helpers.QueryHelper.QueryHelper.getAllLocations();

            foreach(var loc in Location){
                <text>
                    var contentString_@loc.id = "@loc.name";

                    mapMarker_@loc.id = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(@loc.latitude, @loc.longitude),
                        map: map,
                        title: "Hello World!"
                    });

                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString_@loc.id
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker_@loc.id, 'click', function() {
                        infoWindow.open(map, mapMarker_@loc.id);
                    });

                </text>
            }
        }
```

**Updated**

So it shows up as an info box for each location, as I want but the content in it, is only the name of the last location, regardless of the location. Essentially the info box is not tied to any one specific location, even though I have made them all for each id, if that makes sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
          var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {allOverlays: true, controls: []});
            var wms_layer_Test_5000_fKr = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            'Test_5000_fKr',
            'http://130.237.175.39:8080/geoserver/wms/test_test',
            {layers: 'Test_5000_fKr', transparent: "true", format: "image/png"},

            {maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(585000, 6600000, 740000, 6722500), maxResolution: 'auto', projection:"EPSG:3006", units: "m"},
            {isBaseLayer: false}, 
            {visibility: true},
            {transparent: true}
            );

      map.addLayers([wms_layer_Test_5000_fKr]);

      var scalebar = new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine();
            map.addControl(scalebar);

            map.addControl(
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
                    prefix: '<a target="_blank" ' +
                        'href="http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3006/">' +
                        'SWEREF99 TM:&nbsp</a>',
                    separator: ' , ',
                    numDigits: 0,
                    emptyString: 'Mouse is not over map.'
                })
            );            

      var panel = new OpenLayers.Control.NavToolbar();
            map.addControl(panel);

      var panzoom = new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar();
            map.addControl(panzoom);                                              

      var layer = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false});
            map.addControl(layer);

        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      </script>
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to the community if you could add an explanation to your code sample.  Possibly explaining what you did to solve the original posters problem.  This will help everyone learn from your code sample even if they can't run it themselves.